# WP8 Network Share API

Tags: windows-phone-8, smb

For desktop apps, I've used the following to access network shares:

```
    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,
        string password, string username, int flags);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,
        bool force);
```

Are there similar APIs available on WP8 SDK?

Answer (score 2):

No. Windows phone doesn't support network shares. It's not the same as full windows. There is not dllimport or access to native Apis

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible either. Plus I'm sure you don't want to build a small server to serve up files and folders from the targeted computer... but you can do something similar to what the app "Easy Transfer" (http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/easy-transfer/5ccb6655-2ff9-4977-bf8b-577e92bbb236) did and build the app to act as the server.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the direction Pokechu22. I'll try to be more specific with the answer to the question next time by adding relevant code (if any) because it does make better sense to actually answer the question rather than providing suggestions.